# Laravel Email Verification link not working?

Tags: php, laravel, verification, email-verification

I have set up an email verification to my Laravel APP, however when I register as a user and go to mailtrap.io and when I click on "Verify Email Address" button I get 403 This action is unauthorized, HOWEVER if I click on resend verification mail and then click on the button it works fine.

Here are my web routes:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('challenge', 'ChallengesController');
Route::post('/challenge/join/{id}', 'ChallengesController@joinChallenge')->name('challenge.join');
Route::delete('/challenge/finish/{id}', 'ChallengesController@finishChallenge')->name('challenge.finish');
```

In my User model, I have implemented MustVerifyEmail

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $keyType = 'string';

}
```

**UPDATE**
Here is my HomeController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['verified', 'auth']);
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->id();
        $user = User::find($user_id);

        return view('home')
            ->with('challenges', $user->challenges)
            ->with('userChallenges', $user->userChallenges);
    }
}
```

RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:45', 'unique:users'],
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'user_id' => uniqid(),
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: were you not logged in when you clicked the link the first time? And were you logged in when you clicked it second time?

Comment: @ArunAS I was logged in both times, however, after a few tries with new accounts, I figured out that sometimes even it doesn't work from the 2nd time as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't have your authentication paths inside the auth middleware

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

});
```

Comment: What do you mean? What routes should go inside the group you created with middleware auth?

Comment: You should add protected routes, not accesible from not logged users

Comment: Should I add verified middleware to the ChallengesSController?